# Animate a view with Angular/UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm newbie with UI Router. I tried to animate a ui-view in a ui-view.

I have a class "view" for my effect, but this class don't work everywhere.
In my plnker exemple, i want animate build_txt.html with my css, but no effect.
If i tried add this class "view" in my index.html, it's work !

What's the problem ?

The example with [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0RGQXe1he1hQ9R0BhCY?p=preview):

**script.js**

```
.state('build', {
    url: '/build',
    views: {
        '': { templateUrl: 'build.html' },
        'build_txt@build': { templateUrl: 'build_txt.html' }
    }

})
```

**index.html**

```
  <nav id="top">
    <a href="#/about">about</a>
    <a href="#/build">build</a>
  </nav>

  <div ui-view></div>
```

**build.html**

```
<div>Child</div>
<div class="view" ui-view="build_txt"></div>
```

**build_txt.html**

```
<div>My Content</div>
```

Sorry for my poor English, it's my first plunk and i'm french. Thanks !

Comment: You forgot to include `animate.css` so your plunk throws an error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: I have my class "view" in style.css for create animation, i don't need animate.css in this plunker exemple.